# What's the connection between the product of advanced and retarded Green functions and system dynamics in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution

As written in the book *Atom-photon interaction* by Claude Cohen-Tannoudji, the time-evolution operator can be expressed as the Fourier transform of the Green's function
$$
U(\tau)=e^{-iH\tau}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-iE\tau}\left(G_-(E)-G_+(E)\right)dE
$$
where $G_{\pm}(E)=\lim_{\eta\to 0_+}G(E\pm i\eta)$ is the Green's function (GF). But I also notice that, the product of advanced and retarded GF is used to character the dynamics of system
$$
G_-(\tau)G_+(\tau)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-i\omega\tau}G_-(E+\omega)G_+(E)\ d\omega dE,
$$
e.g in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.129.140402), where the Hamiltonian describing the system seen this post [Resolvent (Green's function) of this random matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432306/resolvent-greens-function-of-this-random-matrix).  In some cases I do find that the former expression is not able to predict the correct system dynamics. How is the system dynamics connected with the second expression? Any suggested books or papers will be helpful.

Comment: It is not clear in which way *the product of advanced and retarded GF is used to character the dynamics of system* without reading the paper (to which some may not have access- although there's also the [arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.00704).) I suggest expanding on this in your question (which could be an interesting one.)

Comment: @RogerVadim. I've updated my post. Your comment reminds me that the non-trivial dynamical contribution from the second expression maybe a special case, which occurs in random matrix system.

Comment: The first expression is exact, since $G_{\pm}(E)=\frac{1}{E-H\pm i\eta}$, that is
$G_-(E)-G_+(E)=2\pi i\delta(E-H)$. It may not however work in situations where the Green's functions are approximated. The second expression looks more like a bubble diagram (or perhaps diffusion diagram, with the lines running in the same direction) - it is likely to be used for calculating specific quantities / in specific applications.